# how to show buffered image in imageview

Tags: android, zxing

I'm new to android programming and currently doing research on QRcode using zxing.
I used zxing to encoding a string and now have the bufferedimage returned. Now I want to show this image in the imageview, but looks like that I need to convert it into bitmap first. Can someone tell me a way to do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmap bitMapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("bufferedImage.jpg");